# partitioning a set using a non-equivalence relation

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

I understand that a set can be partitioned into equivalence classes by an equivalence relation ([wikipedia article)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

However can we partition a set into a forest of trees by a relation that's simply transitive (and/or reflexive)?

E.g. assume the transitive, reflexive relation "is prefix of".

Then it seems natural that the set {"abc", "ab", c", "da", "dad", "dab"} can be "partitioned" into the following trees:

```
ab-->abc

da-->dad
  \->dab

c
```

Is the above conceptualization rigorous and what is the proper terminology to describe this kind of "partitioning" ??

Answer (score 1):

A relation that is reflexive and transitive but not necessarily symmetric is called a preorder. See this [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder).

Comment: Your answer got me thinking and resulted in another, more specific, question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/798004/50256